# Failure extracting files when PULLing docker image

Tags: docker, s390x

I'm attempting to pull and run a very simple python application for tests purposes but I'm facing the following issue.
The server where I created the docker image is a Linux on System Z, the same architecture and same Linux distro - SLES 12.5 of the server I would like to pull that.

The /usr size is 30 GBs free so it can not be actual lack of space.

Any ideas about what could it be please?

```
linuxonz1:~# docker run rodgaiotto/my_docker_flask
Unable to find image 'rodgaiotto/my_docker_flask:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from rodgaiotto/my_docker_flask
54e2fb160a5d: Pull complete 
a0f0f1e0f913: Pull complete 
4c7ce4aae52f: Pull complete 
3d5250b872c2: Pull complete 
59c251493ce0: Extracting [==================================================>]  176.7MB/176.7MB
d8d5ba4a8579: Download complete 
10556efc60d2: Download complete 
2417bb4b07f5: Download complete 
698bc892924e: Download complete 
56e11fd21097: Download complete 
b1117af456e9: Download complete 
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): time="2020-04-26T20:28:44-04:00" level=info msg="SUSE:secrets :: enabled"
write /usr/lib/s390x-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6.0.0: no space left on device.
```

inode utilization seems good:

```
Filesystem              Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-usr 2339376 127033 2212343    6% /usr
```

```
zlinuxgpfs1:/ # docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              3                   3                   515.4MB             64.79MB (12%)
Containers          9                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       2                   2                   314.8MB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of simply running `df -h`?

Comment: Please provide an output of `docker info` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
zlinuxgpfs1:~ # df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     2.0G   16K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        2.0G  5.2M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/dasdl1                  2.0G  485M  1.6G  24% /
/dev/mapper/system-usr        37G  2.9G   34G   8% /usr
/dev/mapper/home-home        469M   14M  433M   3% /home
/dev/mapper/optvg-opt        2.7G  729M  1.9G  28% /opt
/dev/mapper/system-srv       1.1G  117M  916M  12% /srv
/dev/mapper/optvg-opt_ibm    4.8G  189M  4.4G   5% /opt/IBM
/dev/mapper/system-support   190M   79M  111M  42% /usr/local/support
/dev/mapper/system-cit       584M   14M  543M   3% /opt/tivoli/cit
/dev/mapper/system-ibm_itm   976M  176M  749M  20% /opt/IBM/ITM
/dev/mapper/system-var       4.7G  4.4G  307M  94% /var
/dev/mapper/system-tmp       976M  375M  551M  41% /tmp
/dev/mapper/system-var_chef  5.0G  435M  4.6G   9% /var/chef
tmpfs                        401M     0  401M   0% /run/user/0
overlay                      4.7G  4.4G  307M  94% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/16a863946c2594c935a6aa6089b7cce51059cbfb2a5ee3bc41379540de601f4f/merged
tmpfs                        2.0G  8.0K  2.0G   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/7fac1c86873cf2c7590b23050fb329937bf0ca67fa006a441d9ff3b9377a6593/mounts/secrets
tmpfs                        401M     0  401M   0% /run/user/191
zlinuxgpfs1:~ # docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 19.03.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: oci runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc version: 3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.12.14-122.12-default
 Operating System: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: s390x
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.911GiB
 Name: zlinuxgpfs1
 ID: TL2X:7ROX:C4TB:DQNX:K74D:3H75:WXFN:AQHJ:VPIR:XXXG:6JI4:GIDO
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
zlinuxgpfs1:~ #
```

Thanks folks, I'm wondering about the "overlay" docker filesystem. Interesting!